# How to get ServerHello and ClientHello from TLS handshake using Java 17+

Tags: java, ssl, sslsocketfactory, handshaking

I want to see more details that happen during the handshake between my application and the server.
Specifically, I'm trying to access the ServerHello and ClientHello objects. Until Java 16, the **sun.security** package was used for this purpose, however, that package was removed from Java 16. I use java 17. Handshake is executed successfully, I use **SSLSocket** for which I have set parameters to connect to the server, and **SessionHolderHandshakeCompletedListener** object through which I extract the certificates that I get from the server. But I'm missing the part that would detect the ClientHello and ServerHello happening during the session. And none of the built methods offered by these objects (sslSocket and sessionHolder) help me to access these objects. Can you point me to some example or documentation so that I can understand what is happening in the background of the tls handshake?

I created SSLSocket to my server, and set all the necessary parameters. Also, I set the SessionHolderHandshakeCompletedListener to listen when handshake is completed. I expect to extract ClientHello and ServerHello from the session, but none of methods does not seem to help.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to access. ClientHello & ServerHello messages are binary messages. I suppose you could access those by using a `FilterInputStream` and `FilterOutputStream` between SSL and the TCP socket's in- and outputstream. You can also enable tracing using the properties that are set when you launch your application, but that info won't be directly accessible in your own application.

Comment: Thank you Maarten. I enabled ssl logging and found ServerHello.java with all it's attributes in the log. So, I thought I could access that object in my app. Do you have any example how to access by using a FilterInputStream and FilterOutputStream as you mentioned?